# How does an exception know if it's being handled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

When raised, `SystemExit` causes the interpreter to exit, *unless* the exception is handled.

```
try:
    raise SystemExit()
except SystemExit:
    print('not today')
# Continue flow...
```

I want to mimic that behavior and write my own exception which executes some code only if the exception isn't caught.

Obviously this wouldn't work:

```
class MyFatalError(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        import sys
        sys.exit()

try:
    raise MyFatalError()
except MyFatalError:
    print('never gets here')
```

(...because an  `__init__` executes on instantiation, regardless of whether the error is handled.)

Is there a (straightforward and pythonic) way to make an exception behave differently when being handled?

Comment: try....except...else should do the trick.

Comment: @Dschoni I am asking how the exception knows if it's being handled and can change behavior based on that. I am not asking about how to handle an exception. My `SystemExit` example demonstrates that it's being done by at least some exceptions from the standard lib.

Comment: the standard lib is AFAIK implemented in C.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be thinking of `SystemExit` as a normal exception. All higher-level languages have a function to shut down the process immediately, and that would be `sys._exit()` in python, but there is also `sys.exit()` that does kinda the same, but allows your `finally` blocks to run first, and is implemented as an exception.

What you want should be done by having a `try - except` block at the lowest level of your application. The behaviour should be in the handler code, not in the exception.